# Loading large CSV file to MySQL with Django and transformations

Tags: mysql, django, csv, import

I have a large CSV file (5.4GB) of data. It's a table with 6 columns a lot of rows. I want to import it into MySQL across several tables. Additionally I have to do some transformations to the data before import (e.g. parse a cell, and input the parts into several table values etc.). Now I can either do a script does a transformation and inserts a row at a time but it will take weeks to import the data. I know there is the LOAD DATA INFILE for MySQL but I am not sure how or if I can do the needed transformations in SQL.

Any advice how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my limited experience you won't want to use the Django ORM for something like this. It will be far too slow. I would write a Python script to operate on the CSV file, using Python's `csv` library. And then use the native MySQL facility `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load the data.

If the Python script to massage the CSV file is too slow you may consider writing that part in C or C++, assuming you can find a decent CSV library for those languages.

Comment: Yeah I guess that is the preferred way. Thanks for the advice.